# c# dataset hasandbelongtomany relationship

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, dataset, relational-database

I would like to ask how to create and query the dataset hasandbelongtomany relationship. For example:
1 Calculation has many Tags.
1 Tags belongtomany Calculations.

The sql query will query by tag and display all calculations with tag.

I am sorry for my broken english, I am looking for setup dataset with many-to-many relationship which the concept is similar to this.

```
//Let’s Add a Student class to program.

public class Student  
{  
   public int StudentID { get; set; }  
   public string StudentName { get; set; }  
   public Grade Grade { get; set; }  
}  
public class Grade  
{  
   public int GradeId { get; set; }  
   public string GradeName { get; set; }  
   public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }  
}  
public class StudentGradeDB : DbContext  
{  
   public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }  
   public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }  
}
```

This is what I found in the http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx, however I am looking to deploy this concept in dataset and datatables

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you're asking, please post some code and further clarify what it is you're after.

Comment: I am sorry for my broken english, I am looking for setup dataset with many-to-many relationship which the concept is similar to this.

Comment: To do the Many-to-Many relationship with DataTables in a Dataset you need to use Relations, here is an example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74a438d2-816f-48dc-9464-f58506c395c8/datarelation-problem-with-manytomany-relationship?forum=csharplanguage